# How to add/change (woocommerce) product tab icon

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm currently trying to develop a plugin for wordpress. There will be a another tab alongside the other product tabs like: 'General', 'Inventory', 'Shipping'. But I can't figure out how to change the icon in PHP.

https://snag.gy/OzxBAW.jpg <-- example

It's really hard to google on this because I get results about adding/changing the product tabs on the website itself. Like 'Description' and 'Reviews'.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that these icons are just added with a CSS `::before` selector.

So if you have something like that to set up your custom tab:

```
function woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs(){ ?>

    <li class="custom_tab">
        <a href="#custom_tab_data_mytab">
            <?php _e('My Custom Tab', 'textdomain'); ?>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php }
```

Than you should be able to style the `a::before` with something like this :

```
#woocommerce-coupon-data ul.wc-tabs li.custom_tab a::before,
#woocommerce-product-data ul.wc-tabs li.custom_tab a::before,
.woocommerce ul.wc-tabs li.custom_tab a::before {
    font-family: Dashicons;
    content: "\f111";
}
```

You can see that we are targeting the `a` inside our new list element. We can target the `a` because we added a unique class to our list item, `<li class="custom_tab">`.

Here you can change the `font-family` and also the `content`, so you can add your own icon font. Just check the styling with the developer tools in your browser.

So for example you could add the new styles directly into the function where you create your list item: (tested)

```
function woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs(){ ?>
    <style>
        #woocommerce-coupon-data ul.wc-tabs li.custom_tab a::before,
        #woocommerce-product-data ul.wc-tabs li.custom_tab a::before,
        .woocommerce ul.wc-tabs li.custom_tab a::before {
            font-family: Dashicons;
            content: "gg";
        }
    </style>

    <li class="custom_tab">
        <a href="#custom_tab_data_mytab">
            <?php _e('My Custom Tab', 'textdomain'); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php }
```

Now you will see not the default icon, instead you will see "gg".

Comment: Thanks for your input! I created a seperate stylesheet which I defined in the main php file, for my plugin. So it gets loaded in to the wordpress dashboard. It seems to work ok...

Comment: Yes, enqueuing a stylesheet is always the preferred way. However if it is just a small or even single line of css, I tend to just add the styles inline or like this. As a full enqueue would be a bit of an overhead.